# How to do log-transform the y variable with file that contains timestamps of user logins in a particular geographic location?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data file with timestamps that look like this if I do data.head()

```
   login_time
0   2016-01-01 00:11:52
1   2016-01-01 00:13:00
2   2016-01-01 00:14:49
3   2016-01-01 00:21:00
4   2016-01-01 00:23:05
```

I need to aggregate this data into 10 minute time intervals; I was trying to take the log transform of the data but I don't know how to best do this? To set up for time series forecasting? Should I create a new column in the data frame df["value"]=1?

For the 15 minute intervals I was going to do

```
df['Value'] = 1

# Resample
print(df.set_index('login_time').resample('10Min').sum())
```

but I do not know if this is correct, and then how would I take the log transform? I am trying to set this up best so I can do prophet

Comment: have you tried `np.log`?

Comment: well i dont know what to take the np.log of because I only have one column

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thats what I want to do but I dont know what my y should be, I dont have a dependent variable because I only have one column

Comment: So, it seems you need to figure out what you are trying to do. StackOverflow is for *programming* questions. You might want to try CrossValidated.

Comment: That is not valid R code (removed its tag and the 2 others that don't apply, either). If it were R, you might use `log( table( cut( data$login_time, breaks="10 min")))`, but doing a log transform of items than might be zero within a 10 minute block of time may generate errors.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can use:

```
print(df.set_index('login_time').resample('10Min').size().reset_index(name='COUNT'))
           login_time  COUNT
0 2016-01-01 00:10:00      3
1 2016-01-01 00:20:00      2
```

If then if need apply [`log`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html):

```
print(df.set_index('login_time').resample('10Min').size().apply(np.log))
login_time
2016-01-01 00:10:00    1.098612
2016-01-01 00:20:00    0.693147
Freq: 10T, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The count column is a problem though because I am trying to do the log transform and with count it the log probability evaluates to log(0), i.e. negative infinity.

Comment: Hmmm, I have no idea what you need. Because [log](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) id function which can be apply for  some numeric values. So is possible use `print(df.set_index('login_time').resample('10Min').size().apply(np.log))`, but still not sure if need this.

Comment: this is the error I get back, RuntimeError: Rejecting initial value:
  Log probability evaluates to log(0), i.e. negative infinity.
  Stan can't start sampling from this initial vaue. so I assume that I need to change the ....I think i must have to change the parameters? how should i do this?